# How to return a cell in tableview if it is nested inside an if statement

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my code —- I am getting error when returning cell1 inside the if statement as it says ” Cannot return a non void return value in void function.I want to return the cell in tableview .. and i have 3 kind of posts .. one for status one for image one for video post. How can i return the cell for each.

P.S. : I have just provided the code for one post type only as if one is solved then all other can be solved.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , 
UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var feedTable: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    feedTable.dataSource = self
    feedTable.delegate = self

}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 376
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    Alamofire.request("https://new.postpfgsdfdsgshfghjoves.com/api/posts/get_all_posts").responseJSON { response in

        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

            if let successcode = dict["STATUS_CODE"] as? Int {
                if successcode == 1 {
                    if let postsArray = dict["posts"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
                    {
                        for i in 0..<postsArray.count
                        {
                            let posttype = postsArray[i]["media_type"] as! String
                            if posttype == "image"
                            {
                                let cell1 : ImageTableViewCell = self.feedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageReuse") as! ImageTableViewCell

                                cell1.fullName = postsArray[i]["full_name"] as? String
                                cell1.profileImageURL = postsArray[i]["profile_pic"] as? String
                                cell1.location = postsArray[i]["location"] as? String
                                cell1.title = postsArray[i]["title"] as? String
                                cell1.postTime = postsArray[i]["order_by_date"] as? String
                                cell1.likes = postsArray[i]["liked_count"] as? Int
                                cell1.comments = postsArray[i]["comment_count"] as? Int
                                cell1.imageURL = postsArray[i]["profile_pic"] as? String
                                cell1.imageLocation = postsArray[i]["location"] as? String
                                cell1.content = postsArray[i]["content"] as? String



                                cell1.profileFullName.text = cell1.fullName
                                cell1.titleImagePost.text = cell1.title
                                cell1.postLocation.text = cell1.location
                                cell1.profileUserLocation.text = cell1.location
                                cell1.numberOfLikes.text = "\(cell1.likes!) Likes"
                                cell1.numberOfComments.text = "\(cell1.comments!) Comments"
                                cell1.postTimeOutlet.text = postsArray[i]["posted_on"] as? String
                                                        let url = URL(string: cell1.imageURL!)
                                                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
                                cell1.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                let url1 = URL(string: cell1.imageURL!)
                                let data1 = try? Data(contentsOf: url1!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
                                cell1.postedImage.image = UIImage(data: data1!)
                            //        return cell1
                            }


                            else if posttype == "status"
                            {

                                let cell1 : StatusTableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "statusReuse") as! StatusTableViewCell

                                                            cell1.fullName = postsArray[i]["full_name"] as? String
                                                            cell1.profileImageURL = postsArray[i]["profile_pic"] as? String
                                                            cell1.location = postsArray[i]["location"] as? String
                                                            cell1.title = postsArray[i]["title"] as? String
                                                            cell1.postTime = postsArray[i]["order_by_date"] as? String
                                                            cell1.likes = postsArray[i]["liked_count"] as? Int
                                                            cell1.comments = postsArray[i]["comment_count"] as? Int
                                                            cell1.postContent = postsArray[i]["content"] as? String


                                                            cell1.profileFullName.text = cell1.fullName
                                                            cell1.titleStatusPost.text = cell1.title
                                                            cell1.postLocation.text = cell1.location
                                                            cell1.profileUserLocation.text = cell1.location
                                                            cell1.content.text = cell1.postContent
                                                            cell1.numberOfLikes.text = "\(cell1.likes!) Likes"
                                                            cell1.numberOfComments.text = "\(cell1.comments!) Comments"
                                                            cell1.postTimeOutlet.text = "\(cell1.postTime!)"

                                                            let url = URL(string: cell1.profileImageURL!)
                                                            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
                                                            cell1.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
//                                    return cell1

                            }

                            else if posttype == "video"
                            {
                                let cell1 : VideoTableViewCell = self.feedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "videoReuse") as! VideoTableViewCell

                                                            cell1.fullName = postsArray[i]["full_name"] as? String
                                                            // cell1.profession = postsArray[i]["profession"] as? String
                                                            cell1.profileImageURL = postsArray[i]["profile_pic"] as? String

                                                            cell1.location = postsArray[i]["location"] as? String
                                                            cell1.title = postsArray[i]["title"] as? String
                                                            cell1.postTime = postsArray[i]["order_by_date"] as? String
                                                            cell1.likes = postsArray[i]["liked_count"] as? Int
                                                            cell1.comments = postsArray[i]["comment_count"] as? Int
                                                            cell1.videoURL = postsArray[i]["profile_pic"] as? String

                                                cell1.profileFullName.text = cell1.fullName
                                                            cell1.titleVideoPost.text = cell1.title
                                                            cell1.postLocation.text = cell1.location
                                                            cell1.profileUserLocation.text = cell1.location
                              //  return cell1
                                                        }

                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your code cannot work. It seems that you completely misunderstand how table views work. The code in `cellForRow...` is not related to the passed index path. There are millions of tutorials how to populate a table view (even with asynchronous tasks like Alamofire / URLSession)

Comment: Can u show me how i can improve it ? i tried very much to search for any tutorial but didnt find any .. Also m just a fresher so its a little difficult for me

Comment: The answer of Andrey describes the basic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer isn't any different from the others but let me be a little more specific.  I'll use a generic example and you'll need to tailor this to your specific needs.

1) Define a model somewhere for your data such as:

```
class MyDataItem {
    var name: String
    var title: String
    var location: String

    init(name: String, title: String, location: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

2) Define an array in your Viewcontroller such as:

```
var dataArray = [MyDataItem]()
```

3) Load the data which you *could* do from the viewDidLoad method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    feedTable.dataSource = self
    feedTable.delegate = self
    loadData()
}
```

4) Implement loadData() function:

```
func loadData() {
    // Here put in your alamo enclosure to retrieve the data and store it into the array you've defined

   // When done, call reload data
   feedTable.reloadData()
}
```

5) Your cellForRowAt function will need to be modified to retrieve the data from the array.  For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell1 : ImageTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageReuse") as! ImageTableViewCell

    cell1.fullName = dataArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell1.title = dataArray[indexPath.row].title
    cell1.location = dataArray[indexPath.row].location

    return cell1
}
```

Anyway, this is the general idea on how to do what you are attempting.  When reloadData is called from your loadData function, it will cause the tableview to reload from the array data correctly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you do not return the cell, you simply make some async request with alamofire and return an instance of the cell from the closure.

`func foo() -> Int { return 1 }` ≠ `func bar() -> Int { someClosure { return 1 } }`

Firstly you need load the the data from `https://www.example.com/api/posts/get_all_posts` into some data model.

```
var models: [SomeTypeYouCreate] = []

func loadData() {
   Alamofire.request(...).responseJSON { response in
      self.models = /* Create array of `SomeTypeYouCreate` objects from response */
      self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}

func func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let model = self.models[indexPath.row]
   // configure cell with model
   return cell
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code to show exactly what i am trying to do. Please have a look and let me know how can i correct it. Thanks for your answer bdw :)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you are returning value in closure Alamofire.request. If you wanna use cell after you confirm cell values, you want to pass over completion handler to the function and use it in that Alamofire.reqeust...

But if I were you, I would create another function which is called before/after tableView function.

If it is **Before** then trigger tableview initialization upon alamofire completion.

If it is **After** then reload when values are loaded correctly in Alamofire.

EDITED:
Like other suggested,**it is bad idea to load data in tableView function.** Also, by using Alamofire, it means you use Closure. That is, whatever you wanna do in Alamofire happens asynchronously, meaning **by the time what you want to achieve in Alamofire is done, your program can be out of the table view function.** Also, **since it is closure, returning value in Alamofire does not satisfy your tableView return type.**

So basically, if you need data via API and verify, you declare function such that do whatever you doing Alamofire and then reload the tableView.

So flow is like this:
1) Make an empty array and put array.count to # of rows.

2) Since it is empty, when tableView first try to generate cells, it doesn't do anything.

3) You call the function which uses Alamofire. If returned values are good, then add the cell(model) to the array.

4) After you are done loading models, do **tableView.reload()**.

5) Tableview calls tableView function now it finds value in array so that will create cells.

Comment: I have updated my code to show exactly what i am trying to do. Please have a look and let me know how can i correct it. Thanks for your answer bdw :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it the way you're trying to. You're not returning a cell from `cellForRowAt` method, you're returning it in Alamofire callback closure. What you should do is to return the cell in your `cellForRowAt` method, and implement some sort of `setup` method for your `UITableViewCell` subclass and make your calls in there

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell1 : ImageTableViewCell = self.feedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageReuse") as! ImageTableViewCell

    // put your Alamofire code inside such function in your UITableViewCell subclass
    cell.setup()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: making a network request each time the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree, however he asked what's the reson reason of compilation error, not to rework his app's architecture.

Comment: I have updated my code to show exactly what i am trying to do. Please have a look and let me know how can i correct it. Thanks for your answer bdw :)